# Sinatra - Controller like setup with auto load/include?

Tags: sinatra, autoload

I like how Rails has each controller in it's own file and it's automatically loaded and I'm trying to do the same for my Sinatra site.

I have, for example, my "Users" pages, which is `users/login`, `users/logout` and so on, what I'd like to do is seperate all these, and other pages, like news, admincp, and so on into their own files.

How would I go about having them auto loaded when my Sinatra site is started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I accomplished this with my project.

I put all the "controllers" in a directory, I then created a file named `init.rb` with the following code:

```
Dir.glob(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/*.rb').each do |controller|
 require(controller)
end
```

Then in my main app file the following code:

```
__DIR__ = ::File.dirname(__FILE__)
require __DIR__ + '/controllers/init'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You again! Let me try this and again, get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more gems you can use the super tiny [`require_all`](https://github.com/jarmo/require_all). It would then be as easy as:

```
require_all 'controllers/init'
```

A lot easier on the eye but on the other hand an added dependency.